# Scala functional programming concepts instead of multiple for loops

Tags: regex, scala, for-loop, collections, functional-programming

I am trying to learn functional programming in Scala. Right now I'm using the OOP way of having for loops to do a job. I have two lists `userCurrentRole` and `entitlements` over which I'm doing a double for loop:

```
for {
    curr <- userCurrentRole {
    ent <- entitlements
} {
        if (ent.userEmail.split("@")(0) == curr.head) {
            if (ent.roleName != curr(1)) {
                grantOrRevoke += 1
                grantList += SomeCaseClass(curr.head, ent.roleName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to convert this double for loop into a logic that uses `map` or `filter` or both or any functional programming features of scala, but without a `for` loop?

EDIT 1: Added a list addition inside the double if..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
val grantOrRevoke = userCurrentRole
    .map(curr => entitlements
        .filter(ent => ent.userEmail.split("@")(0) == curr.head && ent.roleName != curr(1))
        .size)
    .sum
```

Answer (score 3):

The good news is: you are already using functional style! Since the `for` is not a loop per se, but a "for comprehension", which desugars into `flatMap` and `map` calls. It's only easier to read / write.

However, the thing you should avoid is mutable variables, like the `grantOrRevoke` thing you have there.

```
val revocations = for {
    curr <- userCurrentRole {
    ent <- entitlements
    if ent.userEmail.split("@")(0) == curr.head
    if ent.roleName != curr(1)
} yield {
  1
}

revocations.size // same as revocations.sum
```

Note that the `if`s inside the for block (usually) desugar to `withFilter` calls, which is often preferable to `filter` calls, since the latter builds up a new collection whereas the former avoids that.

Comment: @Sparker0i just yield `SomeCaseClass(curr.head, ent.roleName)` instead of `1` and you will get a `List[SomeCaseClass]`

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are already using some higher order functions, only that you don't notice it, because you believe those are for loops, but they aren't loops. They are just sugar syntax for calls to `map` & `flatMap`. But in your case, also to `foreach` and that plus mutability, is want doesn't make it functional.

I would recommend you to take a look to the **scaladoc**, you will find that collections have a lot of useful methods.
For example, in this case, we may use `count` & `sum`.

```
val grantOrRevoke = userCurrentRole.iterator.map {
  // Maybe it would be better to have a list of tuples instead of a list of lists.
  case List(username, userRole) =>
    entitlements.count { ent =>
      (ent.userEmail.split("@", 2)(0) == username) && (ent.roleName == userRole)
    }
}.sum
```